# Strategy did not generate any orders throughout the testing range

Tags: pine-script

New in Pine Script. Took others indicator and tried to rebuilt it into a strategy. The problem is strategy did not generate any orders throughout testing range.

[It's appear on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYmW0.png)

[But it's not generate any order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61COm.png)

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
strategy("Strategy", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 300, max_labels_count = 300, max_bars_back=300)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
h = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth', minval = 0)
mult = input.float(3., minval = 0)
src = input(close, 'Source')

repaint = input(true, 'Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = 'Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

//Style
upCss = input.color(color.teal, 'Colors', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.red, '', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Gaussian window
gauss(x, h) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Append lines
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
n = bar_index

var ln = array.new_line(0) 

if barstate.isfirst and repaint
    for i = 0 to 299
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//End point method
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var coefs = array.new_float(0)
var den = 0.

if barstate.isfirst and not repaint
    for i = 0 to 299
        w = gauss(i, h)
        coefs.push(w)

    den := coefs.sum()

out = 0.
if not repaint
    for i = 0 to 299
        out += src[i] * coefs.get(i)
out /= den
mae = ta.sma(math.abs(src - out), 299) * mult

upper = out + mae
lower = out - mae
 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Compute and display NWE
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
float y2 = na
float y1 = na

nwe = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint
    sae = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(299,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(299,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2 := sum / sumw
        sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        nwe.push(y2)
    
    sae := sae / math.min(299,n - 1) * mult
    for i = 0 to math.min(299,n - 1)
        if i%2
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss)
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss)
        
        if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        
        y1 := nwe.get(i)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Dashboard
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1
  , bgcolor = #1e222d
  , border_color = #373a46
  , border_width = 1
  , frame_color = #373a46
  , frame_width = 1)

if repaint
    tb.cell(0, 0, 'Repainting Mode Enabled', text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plot
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
plot(repaint ? na : out + mae, 'Upper', upCss)
plot(repaint ? na : out - mae, 'Lower', dnCss)

//Crossing Arrows
plotshape(ta.crossunder(close, out - mae) ? low : na, "Crossunder", shape.labelup, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▲', textcolor = upCss, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ta.crossover(close, out + mae) ? high : na, "Crossover", shape.labeldown, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▼', textcolor = dnCss, size = size.tiny)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

buy = ta.crossunder(close, out - mae)
sell = ta.crossover(close, out + mae)

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (sell)
    strategy.close("Long")

if (sell)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (buy)
    strategy.close("Short")
```

I'm cheking in BTC/USDT(BINANCE) pair on tradingview.
[It's appiers on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6z7.png)

[But don't generate any orders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afqb4.png)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I uncheck **Repainting Smoothing**, I see more than 100 entries.

Comment: Look into the `out` and `mae` variables and their dependency from the `repaint` variable